# Combining multiple FirebaseListObservables

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

```
const placeId = this.getPlaceId();
        this.af.database.list(`placeUsers/${placeId}`).subscribe((userKeys) => {
            for (let index = 0; index < userKeys.length; index++) {
                let userKey = userKeys[index];

                this.af.database.list(`userDevices/${userKey.$key}`).subscribe((deviceKeys) => {

                    for (let index = 0; index < deviceKeys.length; index++) {
                        let deviceKey = deviceKeys[index];

                        this.af.database.object(`devices/${deviceKey.$key}`).subscribe((device) => {

                            console.log(device);
                            // Device received.    

                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I'm currently trying to send notifications to all my users that are following a place. The current flow goes like this:

- Getting the users that belong to a place (placeUsers node)
- Getting the deviceKeys that belong to the users (userDevices node)
- Getting the devices from the deviceKeys (devices node)

I was wondering if there was a way to combine all these calls into a single observable call.

What my current problem is, is that i am unable to know when all of these requests are done. I've looked into RxJs, which would allow me to combine all these observables. But i haven't found a good solution on how to do it with four nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `concatMap` and `forkJoin` to compose an observable that emits the devices. This composed observable will emit a single array of devices and will then complete (as the `first` operator is used to take only the first emitted list or object):

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/forkJoin';

this.af.database
  .list(`placeUsers/${placeId}`)
  .first()
  .concatMap(userKeys => {
    let observables = userKeys.map(userKey => this.af.database
      .list(`userDevices/${userKey.$key}`)
      .first()
    );
    return observables.length ?
      Observable.forkJoin(...observables, (...lists) => [].concat(...lists)) :
      Observable.of([])
  })
  .concatMap(deviceKeys => {
    let observables = deviceKeys.map(deviceKeys => this.af.database
      .object(`devices/${deviceKey.$key}`)
      .first()
    );
    return observables.length ?
      Observable.forkJoin(...observables) :
      Observable.of([])
  })
  .subscribe(devices => console.log(devices));
```

If you want an observable that does not complete and emits the devices for a place whenever the users for a places or their devices change, use `switchMap` instead of `concatMap`, `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin` and remove the `first` operators:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

this.af.database
  .list(`placeUsers/${placeId}`)
  .switchMap(userKeys => {
    let observables = userKeys.map(userKey => this.af.database
      .list(`userDevices/${userKey.$key}`)
    );
    return observables.length ?
      Observable.combineLatest(...observables, (...lists) => [].concat(...lists)) :
      Observable.of([])
  })
  .switchMap(deviceKeys => {
    let observables = deviceKeys.map(deviceKeys => this.af.database
      .object(`devices/${deviceKey.$key}`)
    );
    return observables.length ?
      Observable.combineLatest(...observables) :
      Observable.of([])
  })
  .subscribe(devices => console.log(devices));
```

Comment: What purpose does using the spread operator on the observable arrays (`...observables`) serve here if `forkJoin` & `combineLatest` can each take an array argument as well?

Comment: @patrick There is no technical reason. It's just to keep an already lengthy answer as straight-forward as possible. The documentation (such that it is) doesn't (or didn't) make it very clear that you could pass an array, so I didn't want to have to explain that. Also, I seem to remember that (during the beta, at least) there were some operators that didn't accept an array argument, but they all worked with the spread syntax.

Comment: @patrick I can offer another reason for favouring the spread syntax, as it has just bitten me. Some methods - like `Observable.concat` - will treat an array as an [ObservableInput](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html) - and will concatenate the array's elements - so I think things are more consistent between methods if the spread syntax is used.