# Firebase Multiple Joins AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have the following firebase data structure:

```
firebase-database-1234:
  user_keywords (list)
    keyword_a
    keyword_b

  keywords (object)
    keyword_a
      name
    keyword_b
      name

  keyword_posts (list)
    keyword_a
      postkey1
      postkey2
      postkey3
    keyword_b
      postkey4
      postkey5

  posts (object)
    postkey1
      date_time
      title
      etc
    postkey2
      date_time
      title
      etc
    postkey3
      date_time
      title
      etc
    postkey4
    postkey5
```

Basically what I am trying to do is have a structure where a user has tags or keywords that they use to retrieve posts. Each user_keywords node has keywords that the user has selected. I need to get all keywords that match in the keywords node so I can get the name property, etc.

Then I need to get a list of post keys from the keyword_posts node that match the keywords the user selected.

I then loop through each post key property and get the actual post data from the posts node.

I know how to do this using nested subscribes and arrays. But what I really want is a series of observables so I can basically have one observable to subscribe to using the async pipe to get posts.

Here is as far as I've gotten using the current data structure:

```
getKeywordsByUser(userId: string): Rx.Observable<any[]> {
  return this.af.list(`users/${userId}/filters_incoming/keywords`)
    .map(user_keywords => {
      return user_keywords.map(ukw => {
        return this.af.object(`keywords/${ukw.$key}`);
      })
    })
    .flatMap(res => Rx.Observable.combineLatest(res));
}

getPostsByKeywords(userId: string): Rx.Observable<any[]> {
  this.keywords = [];
  return this.getKeywordsByUser(userId)
    .map(keywords => {
      return keywords.map(keyword => {
        this.keywords.push(keyword.name);
        return this.af.list(`keyword_posts/keywords/${keyword.$key}/posts`, {
          query: {
            limitToLast: 33,
            orderByKey: true
          }
        })
        .map(post_keys => {
          return post_keys.map(post_key => {
            return this.af.object(`posts/${post_key.$key}`)
        });
      });
    });
  })
    .flatMap(res => Rx.Observable.combineLatest(res));
}

this.getPostsByKeywords(this.user.uid)
  .subscribe(sub => {
    console.log('sub = ', sub);
  });
```

It returns an array of arrays:

sub =  (2) [Array(1), Array(8)]0: [FirebaseObjectObservable]1: (8) [FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable]length: 2__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: It seems like you have code but have a hard time making it work. The best way to get help in that type of case is to share the [minimum code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise I see some overlap with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755579/how-to-get-do-a-join-in-angularfire2-database

Comment: This database structure is overly "normalized". I suggest you work backwards, starting with what queries you want to make, then considering what database structure would facilitate being able to execute those queries without requiring "join" type logic, and then figuring out how to write/update database content in that structure, which by the nature of denormalization might end up requiring related or similar data to be written in more than one place.

Comment: Yes I have been considering revising my structure to be less normalized which would cut down on nested queries and joins.

What I am trying to accomplish is a way to have users enter tags to find posts that contain those tags. Ideally if the user enters multiple tags, it would match the posts that contains all of those user entered tags first, then followed by posts that contain one or more tags, followed by posts that might just contain one tag. I've found that pretty hard to figure out.

Comment: I added some code above. I'm pretty close but don't know if I am doing it correctly or not. It returns an array of arrays of FirebaseObjectObservable. So close yet no cigar. :)

Comment: @cartant Your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425705/combining-multiple-firebaselistobservables?answertab=votes#tab-top helped me greatly with the problem mentioned above. Thank you! How can I make sure the items coming back from multiple Firebase lists are distinct? Since your code returns an Observable<any[]> I do not know how to use the operator. It needs to be distinct based on $key.